# How to get a function to print the result from a separate function, but the separate function not print a result.

Tags: python, function, callback

Sorry for the horribly worded post, I've been trying to do this practice test question for hours now, and my brain has turned to mush.
So in a practice quiz for uni we have to call upon a previous function, no global constants or variables are allowed. The quiz server then tests the original function to make sure it works, so it inputs:

```
cost = fun_function(5, 31, 15, 10)
print('5 items cost ${:.2f}'.format(cost))
```

and expects the result:

```
5 items cost $155.00
```

The problem with my code is it auto prints the item cost without the added

```
print('5 items cost ${:.2f}'.format(cost))
```

but if I remove the print element of the code, I dont pass the first question. First question is just the code auto running with the input being 25, and the code has to auto output the desired result, with no added input. Desired output of the code is:

```
25 items cost $607.50
```

So how do I get the code to auto print the result of the main function, without it auto printing for any additional tests.
My code:

```
"""Prints out cost of a group of items with discount if it meets item 
required thresh hold"""

def fun_function(
    n_items, cost_per_item, discount_percent, discount_threshold
    ):
    """Prints out cost of a group of items with discount if it meets item 
    required thresh hold"""
    if n_items > discount_threshold:
        final_cost = (n_items * cost_per_item) * (1 - discount_percent/100)
    elif n_items < discount_threshold:
        final_cost = n_items * cost_per_item
    print('{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(n_items, final_cost))

def main():
    """Deminstrates that the function works as desired"""
    fun_function(int(input("How many items? ")), 27, 10, 20)

main()
```

So I guess I'm asking how do I get main() to print the result, but not have fun_function() print a result

And when I have fun_function() return with main() print as so:

```
return '{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(n_items, final_cost)

print(fun_function(int(input("How many items? ")), 27, 10, 20))
```

I recieve this error:

```
print('5 items cost ${:.2f}'.format(cost))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 4, line 1
builtins.ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 
'str'
```

when I input

```
print('5 items cost ${:.2f}'.format(cost))
```

which is just me literally copy pasting what the quiz server inputs,

Comment: The error message is suggesting that the value you've returned is a string and not an integer or float, so convert it before you `return` with, for example, `float(my_value)` or `int(my_value)` You can even do the conversion on the same line, e.g. `return float(my_result)` assuming your result would safely convert to a float.

Comment: You should not use print statements in your `func_function`. Instead, return the result string(`'{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(n_items, final_cost)`). In `main`, you could use it or not.

Comment: Also, like @hallazzang says, you shouldn't use `print` in `fun_function`, but `return` a value instead. That's what I was going to recommend first, till I read more of your post, and misunderstood when you said "when I have fun_function return..."

Comment: When I have main() return rather than print, I still have the problem of it auto printing the answer, and not waiting for the server to input `print('5 items cost ${:.2f}'.format(cost))`

Comment: @GH05T How do I have `fun_function()` return it as a float or int, because I still need the answer for the test from the quiz server to auto print `25 items cost $607.50` after it inputs the number 25. And to do this do I not need the `('{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(n_items, final_cost))`

Comment: @JaredRendell Just use `return n_items, final_cost` which will return those values (unformatted) in a tuple (notice the comma separating the values). Then you can unpack those values into separate variables outside the function and use `print` on them with `format` just as you tried within the function, like so: `n_items, final_cost = fun_function(int(input("How many items? ")), 27, 10, 20)` Then, on the next line, print the values: `print('{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(n_items, final_cost))`

Comment: @JaredRendell Eventually, you'll learn to rid yourself of this concept and habit of wanting to `print` within functions. Instead, try to make your functions "pure"; that is, they should return **values**. This makes them more portable and useful in the future. Then, make your calls to `print` outside those "pure" functions, in your `main` function.

Comment: Note: `n_items` and `final_cost` are not the parameters used for and within the function, in the description I provided; they are part of the scope of the `main` function. In other worse, `fun_function`, or any other function for that matter, can't access them (or their values), even though they have the same name (as the parameters used in `fun_function`). If this is hard to grasp right now, name them something else (outside the function, when you "unpack" the return values of `fun_function`) to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

@JaredRendell

Assuming your procedure for getting the cost is right (I didn't check it--I'm just trying to make this clearer for you:

```
def fun_function(
    n_items, cost_per_item, discount_percent, discount_threshold):
    """Prints out cost of a group of items with discount if it meets item 
    required thresh hold
    """
    if n_items > discount_threshold:
        final_cost = (n_items * cost_per_item) * (1 - discount_percent/100)
    elif n_items < discount_threshold:
        final_cost = n_items * cost_per_item
    return n_items, final_cost


def main():
    """Deminstrates that the function works as desired"""
    n_items, final_cost = fun_function(int(input("How many items? ")), 27, 10, 20)

    print('{} items cost ${:.2f}'.format(float(n_items), float(final_cost)))


main()
```

Notice, in the `print` call in `main` I added calls to `float` as per your error message. This will ensure the values will be returned as floating-point numbers, if they can be converted to floats (e.g., if they are integers, they'll be able to be converted, for example 1, or 2, or string that could be converted to ints, for example "1" or "2").

In the future, when you feel your brain turning to mush, take a break and do something else for a while. Seriously, you will be surprised just how quickly you come up with a solution to the problem you were stuck the entire day before, on the following day and without even thinking about it.

I'd also recommend starting with a clean slate and rewriting all your code. It is very easy to get yourself stuck in a way of thinking, because you end up becoming dependent on the work you've already accomplished, even if it might be flawed. And it becomes almost impossible to think outside this box when you continue staring at it.